# Passing on the XML from java compute node into ESQL Compute node IBM Message broker

Tags: java, xml, ibm-integration-bus

I am reading an xml file, I want to make changes in one of XML parameter that occurs more than once in different parent tags i.e Ordernumber. Then i want to send the updated XML from java compute node to ESQL compute node. Any help will be appreciated.

File has been read and Ive picked up single tag whereas in my xml schema there are different parent tags containing 'Ordernumber' for which i have to change the value.

My code is 
"/"

```
            synchronized (this) {

                 dom = db.parse(Constant.USER_DIR+ Constant.APP_ROOT_DIR +  
                        + Constant.APP_DIR + "/" 
                        + Constant.CONFIG_DIR+ "/" 
                        + Constant.FILE_NAME);

            }

            Element rootElement = dom.getDocumentElement();
            //Code = new Long[1];  
            NodeList nl = rootElement.getElementsByTagName("Ordernumber");
            if (nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {

                    // get the CallSystem element

                    Element el = (Element) nl.item(i);

    }       
            }
```

Also I know that i will be creating the root element for Outmessage as following but I dont know how to put the whole xml from file into the outmessage. Please help.

```
                message = new MbMessage();
                root = message.getRootElement();
                xmlRoot = root.createElementAsLastChild(MbXMLNSC.PARSER_NAME);
```

Comment: You seem to expect all the job done for you. This doesn't happen on SO. Please make your own effort. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I have read the file but as i am new to IBM websphere message broker, I dont know how will i be doing it. If you can help me it would be nice.

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: Code has been added.

Answer (score 0):

1) Don't read files with code (your synchronized block); rather, use the file nodes.  If you want your message flow to start by reading a file from a polled directory, use the File Input node.  If you want to read a file into the middle of your message flow, use the File Read node.  In either case, set the *Message domain* property on the node's *Input Message Parsing* tab to XMLNSC, which will parse the file contents as XML.

2) Wire the Out terminal of the file node to the In terminal of the Java Compute node (JCN).

3) Within the JCN, use XPath to select all of the instances of elements named "Ordernumber".  To do so, your XPath statement will likely use the descendent axis; see this [reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev).  See this [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac30390_.htm%23ac30390_) for an example of how to get started with the product's API.  You will find the Javadoc for MbXPath in {install path}/docs/JavaAPI/index.html.

4) You don't say what happens in the subsequent ESQL Compute node.  But bear in mind that you likely can do it in the previous JCN, eliminating the ESQL Compute node.

I think these pointers should steer you in the right direction.